# Using strcpy in C++ while defining _CRT_SECURE

Tags: visual-c++, strcpy

im starting to learn C++ (just finished with C) and Im trying to use strings. Ive included the  library, and i get this error when compiling:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4996   'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
```

Now I know that this is due to the risk in buffer overflow, but in my task I have to do it that way.
I've read that adding the `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is suppose to remove that warning, but it doesnt...

Comment: I would recommend using `strncpy` over `strcpy`. It allows you specify the maximum length of characters to copy in to the buffer and avoid writing over the end of buffer and receiving a buffer overflow. `strncpy(char* destination, char* source, size_t num)`. Or, if you're sticking with windows development, `strcpy_s` as suggested in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project setting, C/C++ -> Command Line, add following:

```
/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

This will remove the warning.

Answer (score -1):

Use `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprcessor Definitions.